# Не удается подключиться к базе данных.

Tags: c#, datagrid, база-данных, sql

Была создана WindowsForm с DataGridView, написал код для подключения БД, при попытке запустить форму и подключится к БД выдает следующую ошибку:

Невозможно использовать ''; файл уже используется.

Как можно решить данную проблему?

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Crb
{

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string commandText = "SELECT Номер_п_п, Дата, Дата_чека, Номер_чека, ФИО_Пациента, Дата_и_номер_справки, Количество_баллов, ФИО_врача, Количество_баллов_, ФИО_медсестры, Стоимость_справки FROM Больница";
    string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
        @"D:\диплом\Программа\Больница.mdf";

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ObjExcel;
    private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook;
    private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ObjWorkSheet;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "больницаDataSet.Platnie_uslugi". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
        this.platnie_uslugiTableAdapter.Fill(this.больницаDataSet.Platnie_uslugi);
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        myCommand.Connection = conn;
        myCommand.CommandText = commandText;
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
        DataSet dsBolnica = new DataSet();
        System.Data.DataTable dtPlatnie_uslugi = dsBolnica.Tables.Add("Платные услуги");
        DataColumn ddNumber = dtPlatnie_uslugi.Columns.Add("№ п/п", typeof(Int32));
        ddNumber.Unique = true;
        DataColumn dcData = dtPlatnie_uslugi.Columns.Add("Дата");
        DataColumn dcDataChek = dtPlatnie_uslugi.Columns.Add("Дата чека", typeof(Int32));
        DataColumn dcNumberChek = dtPlatnie_uslugi.Columns.Add("№Чека", typeof(Int32));
        DataColumn dcFIOPacient = dtPlatnie_uslugi.Columns.Add("ФИО пациента");
        DataColumn dcDataSpravki = dtPlatnie_uslugi.Columns.Add("Дата и номер справки");
        DataColumn dcSumBallov = dtPlatnie_uslugi.Columns.Add("Количество баллов", typeof(Int32));
        DataColumn dcFioVracha = dtPlatnie_uslugi.Columns.Add("ФИО врача");
        DataColumn dcSumBallov2 = dtPlatnie_uslugi.Columns.Add("Количество баллов 2", typeof(Int32));
        DataColumn dcFioMedSestri = dtPlatnie_uslugi.Columns.Add("ФИО медсестры");
        DataColumn dcPriceSpravki = dtPlatnie_uslugi.Columns.Add("Стоимость справки", typeof(Int32));
        DataColumn dcPriceBall1 = dtPlatnie_uslugi.Columns.Add("Стоимость_1_балла", typeof(Int32));
        //dcPriceBall1.Expression = "((((Стоимость справки*0.55)/1.302)*0.9)/Количество баллов + Количество баллов2)";
        DataColumn dcPriceBall2 = dtPlatnie_uslugi.Columns.Add("Стоимость 2 балла", typeof(Int32));
        dcPriceBall2.Expression = "Стоимость_1_балла * 2";
        conn.Open();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dsBolnica.Tables["Больница"]);
        conn.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dsBolnica.Tables["Больница"].DefaultView;
```

Comment: показывайте код, показывайте исключение. Гадать на кофейной гуще не хотелось бы

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, это не страшно. Просто сейчас открыт MS Access или иная программа, работающая с этой БД. Закройте её, не получится закрыть вручную - проверьте диспетчер задач. Если всё равно не поможет, перезагрузите комп.
P.S. А что за БД?

Comment: База данных была создана в MS Sql Server 2008, пробовал отключить соединение от базы и перезагружал компьютер, не помогло.

Comment: @mishwey, там точно ничего подозрительного в процессах и службах не висит?

Comment: Все службы SQL остановлены кроме одной (SQL Writer), при попытке остановить службу, открывается окно об отказе доступа.